# How to get the file separator symbol in Qore/Qorus : / or \?

Tags: filesystems, qore

I have a [service](https://qoretechnologies.com/manual/qorus/latest/qorus/serviceapi.html) which refers to some external filesystem resources like html, css, etc, ... which fails to load in Windows because of passing incorrect path to them.

Is there any way I could retrieve the file separator of the operating system in Qorus (I mean slash or backslash depending on the system) so that I could build the proper resource path?

I know there is a function to get the path of a file [normalize_dir()](https://qoretechnologies.com/manual/qorus/latest/qorus/namespaceOMQ.html#a1e5648df906f479e9a2e7f398a7e6b65) 
and based on it can be decided what separator to use

```
       string file_separator = normalize_dir("").find("/") > 0 ? '/' : '\';

       setDefaultResource("html" + file_separator + "index.qhtml");
```

but I was wondering if there is already something in place that return this char (as I was not able to find something similar in the docs) or a similar function that I could reuse.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use Qore string constant `DirSep` described in [documentation](https://docs.qore.org/develop/lang/html/group__system__and__build__constants.html), which always contains the platform-specific directory separator string, i.e. `/` for Linux and other Unix-like OSes, and `\` for Windows.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is what I was looking for.